# How to convert a variable to int in Phalcon's .volt?

Tags: php, variables, int, phalcon, volt

I have this code in .volt (Phalcon):

```
{% set foo = myFunction(data, 'data_source', 0) %}
```

It returns non-negative numbers, the problem is when it's empty I'm getting `""` instead of `"0"`. How can I force volt to always return `int` as `foo`, so everything will work as expected but it won't throw `empty variable` errors?

I'd rather avoid using `<?php ... ?>`.

I've been looking through http://voltframework.com/docs with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options you can choose from:

1) Creating own volt function:

```
$compiler->addFilter(
    'int',
    function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
        return 'intval(' . $resolvedArgs . ')';
    }
);
```

More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#id2

2) Using built in filters from volt. In your case you can use DEFAULT fitler to set default value as 0 if no value is returned. Full list of built in functions here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#filters

And of course other options would be to modify your function to always return a value or use the PHP syntax inside volt, which is a bit ugly :)

Answer (score 2):

...there is another way :) Volt has implemented php [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function with name `format`. So, you can do something like this:

```
{% set foo = myFunction(data, 'data_source', 0) %}

The int of "foo" is: {{ "%d"|format(foo) }}
```

Good luck!